# issue in using RecyclerView adapter and Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I've a RecyclerView adapter as

```
public class AllPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostHolder> {

    private AppCompatActivity mContext;
    private List<Post> postList;

    public AllPostAdapter(AppCompatActivity mContext, List<Post> postList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.postList = postList;

    }

    // skipping other overridden methods

}
```

fetching data from Firebase Database in MainActivity using ChildEventListener as

```
mPostChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            try{
                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.hasChildren() && !dataSnapshot.equals(null)){
                    Post post =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    mPostList.add(post);
                    mAllPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    ///
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
      // skipping other overridden methods
    };

    mPostQuery = getQuery(); // this method only retuns ==> return mPostDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(100);

    mPostQuery.addChildEventListener(mPostChildEventListener);
```

now setting the RecyclerView as

```
mAllPostAdapter = new AllPostAdapter(MainActivity.this, mPostList);
mPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAllPostAdapter);
```

works perfect as it should, but I want to use the method **setEnabled(false);** On a view of RecyclerView item in adapter when it is clicked but I can not, asyou can see

[image]

I want that the *like* button be setEnabled(true); when the *heatrs* are inserted in DB because in onBindViewHolder() method of adapter where I'm setting click listener to *like* button I've to check if the post at the given position is liked by current user then the *like* button should be setEnabled(false); else behave as normal you can see here

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    try{

        final Post model = postList.get(position);    
        viewHolder.likeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(model.getHearts().size()));
// Here I'm if the post at the given position is liked by current user then the _like_ button should be setEnabled(false);
        if (!model.hearts.containsKey(currentUserId)){ 

            viewHolder.likeImageView.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(LikeButton likeButton) {

                    Map<String, Boolean> likeWithUserId = new HashMap<>();

                    likeWithUserId.put(currentUserId, true);

                    mPostDatabaseReference.child(model.getPostId())
                            .child("hearts").setValue(likeWithUserId);

                    viewHolder.likeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(model.getHearts().size() + 1));

                }

                @Override
                public void unLiked(LikeButton likeButton) {

                }
            });

        } else {

            viewHolder.likeImageView.setLiked(true);
            viewHolder.likeImageView.setEnabled(false);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but you can see the line

```
if(model.hearts.containsKey(currentUserId))
```

is not fetching and resulting in real time that is the issue I want to resolve here further questions are welcome and I'll try to answer **if any?**